Gradient accumulation working differently from batch training
as a personal training exercise I'm trying to implement a transformer model to predict the minimum of a set of numbers. The training works well with batch training but it doesn't with gradient accumulation strategy and it just learns to output the mean of the minimums. I tried many things (like dividing the loss by accumulation steps, multiplying lr, printing grads etc.) but it changed nothing. I also made sure that there are no batch normalization layers in my model (it's a normal transformer model plus a simple linear layer after that without any normalization). Here's my train loop:
model = MinValuePredictor().cuda()
model.train()
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
accum_steps = 8 #To test with greater batch training, you can change this to 1
optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.000001)
# Training loop
input_count = 10
epochs = 50000
batch_size = 1
optimizer.zero_grad()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Generate data
    inputs, targets = generate_data(batch_size, input_count)

    # Forward pass
    predictions = model(inputs).squeeze(1)

    loss = loss_fn(predictions, targets) / accum_steps
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Difference: {predictions.item() - targets.item()}")

    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()
    loss.retain_graph = False

    # Perform optimizer step and zero gradients every 8 epochs
    if (epoch + 1) % accum_steps == 0:
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear accumulated gradients

    if (epoch + 1) % 50 * accum_steps == 0:
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}")


# Test the model
test_input, test_target = generate_data(batch_size=1)
test_output = model(test_input).item()
print(f"Test Input: {test_input}")
print(f"Predicted Min: {test_output:.4f}, Actual Min: {test_target.item():.4f}")

Random numbers are generated like that:
#The maximum stays 30.
def generate_data(batch_size=64, n=10):
    min_values = 10 + (5 * torch.rand(batch_size, 1).cuda())  # Random min for each sample
    max_values = 30 * torch.ones(batch_size, 1).cuda()  # Fixed max
    input_tensors = (min_values + (max_values - min_values) * torch.rand(batch_size, n).cuda())
    targets = torch.min(input_tensors, dim=1).values
    return input_tensors, targets

As I said before the code works perfectly well with a batch size of 8 and any accumulation steps, but it behaves as the batch size and accumulation steps are both 1 when the batch size is 1, no matter what the number of accumulation steps is. What am I doing wrong?

Does it work with batch size 2 or 4 with accumulation?

Also double check the tensor sizes. With batch size of 1, you might be losing an axis somewhere causing broadcasting issues
